# Movie where prisoners were forced to swallow a metal GPS tracker that would kill them if they crossed the line

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a older movie a while back where it was in a prison. The prisoners were forced to swallow a metal GPS tracker and a red eye looking computer system would follow them in the ceiling. If they crossed a line, they would be killed by the metal ball in their stomach.

Comment: [Fortress](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106950/)?

Comment: @Valorum Obviously; go for it.

Comment: Omg. Thank you so much. Yes.

Comment: @MojiAlavi: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8):

This is [*Fortress*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106950/) (1992).

The prisoners are force-fed a pill that can track them (and kill them if they cross into any of the [red lined areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShO2h.png)) and the prison is controlled by a green-eyed computer.